# How to select all form elements which are not in a hidden parent in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need only one jQuery select line/selector (due to a JS plugin limitation) to find all `inputs` (hidden type inputs as well !!! i.e. '`<input type=hidden />`') which are not *hidden* due to one of its parent, I tried with this one

```
:parent:not(hidden) input
```

but it doesn't work (should return input2 and input3 only).

Here a jsfiddle showing the issue: [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/frntz/fkhv4ckq/)

Answer (score 4):

When parent is hidden, its descendants are also hidden. Use `:visible` pseudo-selector

```
$('input:visible')
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fkhv4ckq/3/)

**UPDATE**

> to find all inputs (hidden type inputs as well !!!

```
$("input:visible, input[type='hidden']")
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fkhv4ckq/9/)

Comment: I edited my question, your way I cannot retrieve hidden type input as well

Comment: @Frntz Did you check *Demo*

Comment: Yes tushar, but i edited my jsfiddle with a more complex which seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `:visible` selector

```
$("input:visible");
```

**UPDATE**

```
var jqueryselect = ":parent:visible input";
var res = "";
$("body").find(jqueryselect).each(function(i, ele){
    res += $(ele).attr("id") + " ";
});

$("#jqselect").text(jqueryselect);
$("#result").text(res);
```

**UPDATE(AFTER QUESTION CODE UPDATED)([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fkhv4ckq/44/))**

```
var jqueryselect =$("input").filter(function() { return  $(this).parent().is(":visible")  });
var res = "";
$("body").find(jqueryselect).each(function(i, ele){
    res += $(ele).attr("id") + " ";
});

$("#jqselect").text(jqueryselect);
$("#result").text(res);
```

Comment: I edited my question, your way I cannot retrieve hidden type input as well

Comment: I updated the fiddle with this:http://jsfiddle.net/fkhv4ckq/7/. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you hemal but i enhanced my jsfiddle, it seems to not work when an input as many parents

Comment: Please provide more detail with your current fiddle

Comment: Have you checked my fiddle?

Comment: thank you for your response but I really need to base my selection on the inputs based on their visibility from its parents, I updated my jsfiddle and with your response Input4 is showing ...

Comment: @Frntz, Please see my fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/fkhv4ckq/44/. Is it correct?. Also check second updated answer.

Comment: It works but I must make it work with only a single jQuery selector, i'm using a js plugin that just allows me to pass as parameter one jQuery selector string :/